# Handling time zones in Cocoa

Tags: iphone, cocoa, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

I just want to clarify if I am understanding how dates & time zones work.

Basically, I have a date string @"2008-07-06 12:08:49" that I want to convert to an NSDate. I want this date and time to be in whatever the current user's time zone is set in. So if they are in GMT or HST, it's still 12:08:49.

If I have date in unix form 1215382129 (UTC) and my time zone is set to London (GMT), the outputted date from NSLog() is:

2008-07-06 12:08:49 +0100

If I then change my time zone to Hawaii (HST) and output the same date, I get:

2008-07-06 12:08:49 -1000

This seems to work fine, but I was under the impression to get the time in Hawaiian, I'd have to physically add the time difference (-10hrs) to the unix time stamp. Is this not required then?

Does that mean, whatever date and time a unix time is pointing to, it always points to the same date and time in whatever time zone a user is in?

Hope this makes sense!

**Edit**

I've just realised (thanks to Kevin Conner!) that in fact NSDateFormatter is creating different unix timestamps for that date string depending on the current timezone! So I was totally wrong!! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm mostly a Java guy.  But Cocoa seems to work like the Java library in this regard:  Dates are zoneless timestamps.  Time zones are in the domain of *formatting* dates for display.  In other words, the internal format doesn't consider time zones, it's all in UTC.  Time zones are relatively a convenience for humans, so they are in the display/parsing side.

I noticed there is a [`setTimeZone:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setTimeZone:) on `NSDateFormatter`.  Try calling that on your formatter before performing the format.

Comment: Ahh, interesting! I didn't realise `NSDateFormatter` used time zones. It would appear that it's automatically setting it from the system default. And it's creating a different unix timestamps depending on the zone! Thanks for this!

Comment: I haven't confirmed this, but I think you'll find the same to be true of date parsing:  When you parse a date string, it will assume the string is in your system time zone, unless you configure the parser differently.  Cheers :)